# How Do I print a dictionary without the {} and '

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is my Dictionary
At this point it is being updated.

```
DictDestination.update({(listDestinations[intCount]): [(" Discount of ${0:.2f}".format(intDiscount)), ("Thats {0:.2f}% off".format(intPercentage)), ("The saver type is {}".format(strSaverType)), ("Your original price was ${0:.2f}".format(intOriginal)), ("Your new price is ${0:.2f}".format(intNew))]})
```

So far I am using to pprint module to print it and I comes out like this.

```
{   'Auckland': [   ' Discount of $1.00',
                'Thats 1.00% off',
                'The saver type is Quick Saver',
                'Your original price was $1.01',
                'Your new price is $0.01'],
'Rotarua': [   ' Discount of $1.00',
               'Thats 1.00% off',
               'The saver type is Quick Saver',
               'Your original price was $1.01',
               'Your new price is $0.01'],
'Wellington': [   ' Discount of $1.00',
                  'Thats 1.00% off',
                  'The saver type is Quick Saver',
                  'Your original price was $1.01',
                  'Your new price is $0.01']}
```

However I want it to come out something like this

```
Auckland : Discount of $1.0
           Thats 1.00% off
           The saver type is Quick Saver
           Your original price was $1.01
           Your new price is $0.01
Rotarua : Discount of $1.00
          hats 1.00% off
          The saver type is Quick Saver
          Your original price was $1.01
          Your new price is $0.01
Wellington : Discount of $1.00
             That's 1.00% off
             The saver type is Quick Saver
             Your original price was $1.01
             Your new price is $0.01
```

I don't know if there is any sort of module that you can use but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, bear in mind how to ask. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the items of the dictionary using a `for` loop, and print the resulting keys and values using your desired formatting using the `print` function.

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    #do the formatting to print the key/value
    #A loop for the items in embedded lists 
    for list_item in value:
        #print stuff as needed here
        pass
```